# How to solve the issue where nano screen text is scrambled when using su - admin

Tags: terminal, su, nano

In Terminal I `su - admin` while in my user account to `brew update`, modify `.bashrc`, etc.

I have noticed that when in my user session changing the size of the window while running `nano` doesn't scramble the text at all. The window resizes perfectly.

However, after opening a new Terminal window, running `su - admin`, then `nano` and trying to resize - the text is scrambled and there is no way to recover it. `control-l` doesn't work.

When I log into the admin account open Terminal and run `nano` there is no issue with resizing the window — text doesn't scramble.

The same issue happens in reverse. From my admin account using `su - user` and running `nano` and resizing will cause the text to scramble.

Any idea what's happening here and how to resolve this issue?

I am using nano 4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `login` on OS X is a workaround for this issue.

$ `login`

login: `your username`

password: `your password`

Last login: Day Month Date HH:MM:SS on ttys000

$ `whoami`

your username

Thanks to user [grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grg) on [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/126303/40153)

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue has a selected answer, but if you read the manual, what is needed is a screen refresh, using:

```
^L
```

Which is

```
ctrl + L
```

You need to tap it a couple times if for some reason the buffer gets corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal emulator will send a Window Change signal (SIGWINCH) to the shell that was started along with the terminal emulator. The shell is supposed to pass it on to its children - but when you've transitioned to another user account (using `su` or otherwise), it won't be able to signal that shell because it's running as a different user. So the `su`'d shell and any programs run from it will keep using the old window size, oblivious to the fact that the real window size has changed.

To fully update the `su` session to use the new window size, you'll need to run `eval $(resize)` in that shell. It will both update the environment variables COLUMNS and LINES (that's why `eval` is needed), and the terminal settings (equivalent to commands `stty rows` and `stty columns`). In many cases, just `resize` without the `eval...` part might be sufficient, but some programs might need the environment variables too.

Comment: Thank you the background information! Apparently `resize` doesn't exist on macOS natively. But if it did... while I was in `nano` editing a document, how would I send that as a command? Is there an environmental variable I can set or can I add a command while transitioning to another account using `su`?